# HRESULT to string (getting documents path) C++

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, stdstring

I am using the following function to try and obtain the path of the documents folder and then convert that path to std::string:

```
std::string getpath() {
    TCHAR documents[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, documents);
    std::stringstream pff;
    pff << result;
    return pff.str();
}
```

When this executes, I get an "invalid file name error" when trying to append "\filename" to the string.

Please help!

Edit: Here is how I append to the path:

```
std::string folder = getpath() + "\\Folder";
```

I assumed the double escape symbols would still apply.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing `documents`, but `result`.

Try something like this:

```
std::string getpath() {
    TCHAR documents[MAX_PATH];

    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, documents);
    if (result == S_OK) // SUCCEEDED(result) can be problematic
                        // since S_FALSE is a possible return value
    {
        std::stringstream pff;
        pff << documents;
        return pff.str();
    }
    // handle error somehow
    return "";
}
```

---

And this is a Unicode-friendly version:

```
std::wstring getpath() {
    TCHAR documents[MAX_PATH];

    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, documents);
    if (result == S_OK) // SUCCEEDED(result) can be problematic
        // since S_FALSE is a possible return value
    {
        std::wstringstream pff;
        pff << documents;
        return pff.str();
    }
    // handle error somehow
    return L"";
}
```

Comment: documents remains to be TCHAR

Comment: +1 but somewhere you'll need to pass the length of the string buffer into SHGetFolderPath: one of those parameters should not be NULL.

Comment: @Bathsheba It is supposed to be MAX_PATH buffer, see [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I thought I needed to convert the error code result in order to output the path.

Comment: @user3295336 No :). But be aware of `TCHAR`. If your project uses Unicode, you may want to use `wstring` and `wstringstream`.

Comment: This updated function produces the same result. Should I try converting result to LPCTSTR using _com_error then to string?

Comment: @user3295336 I tried, it seems to work for me. Check how you build the complete path. Do you add `\\` after the folder?

Comment: Did you try the Unicode version? And just check the `documents` before printing it. Does it have proper path?

Comment: Actually, the *"Unicode-friendly version"* is a happy mixture of Unicode and generic-text implementations. The Unicode signature is `SHGetFolderPath`, and the final argument is a `wchar_t*`. Plus, it's time to drop the arbitrary `MAX_PATH` limitation. Use [SHGetKnowFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) instead, as pointed out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, `SHGetFolderPathW`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The length of the buffer in the call to [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is implied, and limited to `MAX_PATH` characters. That's just one of the reasons why you should stop calling this API.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails, because you are really constructing a string off of the **return value** (i.e. error code) of [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx). You should be using the returned path instead.

Since `SHGetFolderPath` is deprecated, you should be using [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) instead. Among other things, you won't accidentally construct an MBCS-encoded path name. And there is no arbitrary `MAX_PATH` (260) character limitation.

The following code retrieves the current user's document path<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <string>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <comdef.h>

std::wstring GetDocumentPath() {
    wchar_t* pOut = nullptr;
    // Retrieve document path (CheckError throws a _com_error exception on failure)
    _com_util::CheckError( ::SHGetKnownFolderPath( FOLDERID_Documents, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT,
                                                   nullptr, &pOut ) );
    // Attach returned buffer to a smart pointer with custom deleter. This
    // is necessary, because the std::wstring c'tor throws on failure.
    // Without this smart pointer, any exception would leak memory.
    auto deleter = []( void* p ) { ::CoTaskMemFree( p ); };
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype( deleter )> buffer{ pOut, deleter };
    return std::wstring{ buffer.get() };
    // Invisible: Run deleter for buffer, cleaning up allocated resources.
}
```

Note: `_com_util::CheckError` is not officially documented, so it may become unavailable in a future version of the compiler. A custom implementation with similar functionality might look like this:

```
inline void CheckError( HRESULT hr ) {
    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
        _com_raise_error( hr );
    }
}
```

[_com_raise_error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc6sws56.aspx) is documented to throw a [_com_error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx) exception. The [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) macro is also documented.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The known folder paths are customizable (see [Folder Redirection Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx)). You cannot simply attempt to construct them yourself. You have to ask the Shell for this information.*

Answer (score -2):

I ended up ditching SHGetFolderPath and going with the more straightforward _dupenv_s:

```
std::string getpath() {
    char* buf = 0;
    size_t sz = 0;
    if (_dupenv_s(&buf, &sz, "USERPROFILE") == 0) {
        std::string path(buf);
        path += "\\Documents\\Folder";
        return path;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This fails for systems, where the documents folder is located somewhere else. And since the documents folder is a customizable user setting, your code failing is not just a theoretical possibility. Leaking memory, and using MBCS character encoding just adds to the wrong. Please do take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand, that Stack Overflow is about **quality** answers. This one certainly isn't.

Comment: I thought to leave my answer as it fulfilled the context of the question. I did not specify whether or not the solution should be safe. It was for testing and conceptual purposes in order to train myself. Nonetheless, I guess I should have at least added a try-catch and expressly stated: THIS IS NOT FOR BUSINESS USE.

The "-1" may, therefore, be slightly misguided of you. SO is about **learning**. I will run my answer through the help center next time.

Comment: *"SO is about learning."* - That's wrong. SO is a Q&A site. It's about **solving** issues, with **quality** solutions. I have no idea, how a try-catch block would do any good. If anything, it'll further deteriorate this code. It is wrong for so many reasons, most importantly, it **doesn't** address the question that was asked (see [Folder Redirection Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx) to understand, why it can and will fail). In that light, the down vote is appropriate.